# Using Jasmine Unit Testing With 100+ Tests Of The Same Type

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I recently found [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) for unit testing, and it seems like a good solution for what I'm doing. However, I'm testing somewhere around 100 different possibilities, and I don't want to write the same line of code over and over.

So I made an object full of tests, and I'm looping around the unit test over and over with these tests. It prints out the correct number of tests when I run it. They all pass as shown below.

But then I changed "cero" to "cerFOOBARBAZ" and it still passes, which is wrong.
Then I change 0 to an arbitrary number (993 for example) and it doesn't pass (and it shouldn't, but ALL tests fail.

What's up with that?

```
   var tests = {
        0 : "cero",
        1 : "uno",
        2 : "dos", 
        3 : "tres", 
        4 : "cuatro",
        5 : "cinco",
        6 : "seis", 
        7 : "siete",
        8 : "ocho",
        9 : "nueve",
        10 : "diez",
        11 : "once",
        12 : "doce",
        13 : "trece"

        };

describe("Numbers Return Correctly", function() {

    for(var test in tests) {
        it("Returns Correct String Based On Integer Input", function() {
            var number = parseInt(test);
            expect(number.convertNumToWord("es")).toEqual(tests[test]);
        });
    }
});
```

EDIT: I found out what was the problem. I was running the entire describe multiple times, not single specs.

However, when I do this:

```
    var tests = {
        0 : "cero",
        1 : "uno",
        2 : "dos", 
        3 : "tres", 
        4 : "cuatro",
        5 : "cinco",
        6 : "seis", 
        7 : "siete",
        8 : "ocho",
        9 : "nueve",
        10 : "diez",
        11 : "once",
        12 : "doce",
        13 : "trece"

        };

describe("Numbers Return Correctly", function() {


        //console.log(test);
        //console.log(tests[test]);
        it("Returns Correct String Based On Integer Input", function() {
            for(var test in tests) {
                var number = parseInt(test);
                expect(number.convertNumToWord("es")).toEqual(tests[test]);
            }
        });

});
```

I get the expected output, except there are no fine-grained details on *which* spec didn't pass. Any help there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create a closure for each of your test, otherwise in your first example you are testing only the last value a lot of time. A clean version of it would look like this :

```
describe("Numbers Return Correctly", function() {
    var tests = {  }; // ...

    function addTest(test) {
        it("Returns Correct String Based On Integer Input " + test, function() {
            var number = parseInt(test, 10);
            expect(number.convertNumToWord("es")).toEqual(tests[test]);
        });
    }

    for(var test in tests) {
        addTest(test);
    }
});
```